# Slow updates with MySQL innoDB (clueless)

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I have a fairly simple query that runs super fast *most* of the time and takes up to 30 seconds in other rare occasions. I have no clue as to what is causing it. Here is an example of what I'm talking about.

> mysql> UPDATE matchSessionMembers msm JOIN matchSessions ms ON
>   msm.matchNo = ms.matchNo AND ms.STATUS != 'N' SET msm.STATUS = 'P'
>   WHERE msm.memberNo = 7 AND msm.STATUS = 'M';
>   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
>   Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
>
> mysql> UPDATE matchSessionMembers msm JOIN matchSessions ms ON
>   msm.matchNo = ms.matchNo AND ms.STATUS != 'N' SET msm.STATUS = 'P'
>   WHERE msm.memberNo = 7 AND msm.STATUS = 'M';
>   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
>   Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
>
> **mysql> UPDATE matchSessionMembers msm JOIN matchSessions ms ON msm.matchNo = ms.matchNo AND ms.STATUS != 'N' SET msm.STATUS = 'P'
>   WHERE msm.memberNo = 7 AND msm.STATUS = 'M';
>
>   Query OK, 0 rows affected *(3.01 sec)*
>
>   Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0**
>
> mysql> UPDATE matchSessionMembers msm JOIN matchSessions ms ON
>   msm.matchNo = ms.matchNo AND ms.STATUS != 'N' SET msm.STATUS = 'P'
>   WHERE msm.memberNo = 7 AND msm.STATUS = 'M';
>   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
>   Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
>
> **mysql> UPDATE matchSessionMembers msm JOIN matchSessions ms ON msm.matchNo = ms.matchNo AND ms.STATUS != 'N' SET msm.STATUS = 'P'
>   WHERE msm.memberNo = 7 AND msm.STATUS = 'M';
>
>   Query OK, 0 rows affected *(1.88 sec)*
>
>   Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0**
>
> mysql> UPDATE matchSessionMembers msm JOIN matchSessions ms ON
>   msm.matchNo = ms.matchNo AND ms.STATUS != 'N' SET msm.STATUS = 'P'
>   WHERE msm.memberNo = 7 AND msm.STATUS = 'M';
>   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
>   Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

In this query I have set indexes for all msm.matchNo, ms.matchNo, ms.status, msm.status, and msm.memberNo.

I ran the same query 6 times and had 4 cases where the queries finished in under a second while 2 cases took more than a second to process. I did some more testing and got profile data for one of the more severe cases which took up to 30 seconds to execute this stupid query.

```
mysql> SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 3;  
+---------------------------+-----------+  
| Status                    | Duration  |  
+---------------------------+-----------+  
| starting                  |  0.000075 |  
| checking permissions      |  0.000013 |  
| checking permissions      |  0.000012 |  
| Opening tables            |  0.000073 |  
| checking permissions      |  0.000011 |  
| checking permissions      |  0.000013 |  
| System lock               |  0.000023 |  
| init                      |  0.000021 |  
| updating main table       |  0.000014 |  
| optimizing                |  0.000020 |  
| statistics                |  0.000117 |  
| preparing                 |  0.000028 |  
| executing                 |  0.000011 |  
| Sending data              | 31.940094 | <==
| updating reference tables |  0.000039 |  
| end                       |  0.000016 |  
| end                       |  0.000015 |  
| query end                 |  0.000048 |  
| closing tables            |  0.000039 |  
| freeing items             |  0.000036 |  
| logging slow query        |  0.000011 |  
| cleaning up               |  0.000014 |  
+---------------------------+-----------+
```

I have a few other UPDATE queries with similar symptoms. Why is this query taking so long to execute even though there aren't any rows actually being updated? What could this "Sending data" bottleneck possibly be?

** edit: added CREATE TABLE code for both tables being used

> CREATE TABLE `matchSessionMembers` (
>     `matchNo` int(11) NOT NULL,
>     `memberNo` int(11) NOT NULL,
>     `status` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'M' COMMENT 'M=match, P=pending, Y=saidYes, N=saidNo, D=deleted',
>     `muted` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
>     `deleted` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
>     `regDatetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
>     `exitDatetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY (`matchNo`,`memberNo`),
>     KEY `status` (`status`),
>     KEY `FK_matchSessionMembers_memberNo` (`memberNo`),
>     KEY `regDatetime` (`regDatetime`),
>     KEY `FK_matchSessionMembers_matchNo` (`matchNo`),
>     CONSTRAINT `FK_matchSessionMembers_matchNo` FOREIGN KEY (`matchNo`) REFERENCES `matchSessions` (`matchNo`),
>     CONSTRAINT `FK_matchSessionMembers_memberNo` FOREIGN KEY (`memberNo`) REFERENCES `members` (`memberNo`)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
>
> CREATE TABLE `matchSessions` (
>     `matchNo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     `memberCount` int(11) NOT NULL,
>     `status` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'P' COMMENT 'P=pending, Y=successful, N=unsuccessful, X=expired',
>     `isQuickMatch` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
>     `open` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
>     `regDatetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
>     `activeDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
>     `expireDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY (`matchNo`),
>     KEY `status` (`status`),
>     KEY `activeDate` (`activeDate`),
>     KEY `expireDate` (`expireDate`)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=113912 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: How many rows are we talking about? I mean approx number of rows in these two tables.

Comment: Please try `UPDATE matchSessionMembers msm JOIN matchSessions ms ON msm.matchNo = ms.matchNo SET msm.STATUS = 'P' WHERE msm.memberNo = 7 AND msm.STATUS = 'M' AND ms.STATUS != 'N';` and report back.

Comment: Not a terrible amount. Around 110k for matchSessions and 220k for matchSessionMembers.

Comment: Sending data bottleneck is actually the step before that took that time. It's a known gotcha with query profiling. So the execution is the one responsible for the bottleneck and it's most likely due to number of rows that have to be inspected.

Comment: @N.B. I've thought of that but I can't figure out why the query time is so significantly inconsistent.

Comment: @EugenRieck I tried your query with the same results. :S

Comment: Turn your query into a SELECT query and try again. Also, post the SHOW CREATE TABLE output so we can see the table type and how you indexed your columns.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @N.B. Interesting, SELECTs don't seem to be affected as UPDATEs are. I think it's safe to assume that it's a problem specific to UPDATEs but like I mentioned before, this happens even if the query isn't actually updating anything because there is no row that matches the WHERE/ON condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

A stupid mistake on my part. It wasn't easy to identify though.
I had a different super slow query that ran every hour or so, one update query that was taking over 30 seconds to execute. I'm not perfectly sure but I think that that query must have locked everything down and put all other queries in queue.

I didn't notice it in the slow query logs because it was buried under all the other slow queries that resulted of this one dumb query.

I hope this helps anyone else having similar problems.